# Why Undefined variable when its defined?

Tags: php

I want to "call me!" to display once in the run function .Its displaying $loaded as  Undefined variable when I have defined to Boolean false.

```
    $loaded=FALSE;

    function run(){

        echo "call me!";

        if($loaded) return;
        $loaded=TRUE;
    }

    for($i=1;$i<10;$i++){

        run();
        echo "engine start";

    }
```

> NOTICE Undefined variable: loaded

Comment: Its a notice. It is not defined in the function scope when you do the conditional check

Comment: can u fix it? @frz3993

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$loaded=FALSE;

function run(){

    global $loaded; // add this line

    if($loaded) { 
      return;
    } else {
      echo "call me!";
      $loaded=TRUE;
    }
}

for($i=1;$i<10;$i++){

    run();
    echo "engine start";
}
```

Comment: thanks man actually I wanted to display "call me!" once which I have edited above